# How do I detect if I have a Super AMOLED or LCD Screen on my Nexus S?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, screen, super-amoled

Many sources are citing that the Nexus S is shipping with 2 different types of screen due to Super AMOLED shortages. As I am in the UK it is likely I will have the Super LCD, which I read somewhere is inferior compared to the Super AMOLED.

How can I tell which one I have? What are the main differences?

**Update:** 
Found the answer here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1022216

Looking in 'Baseband version' under 'About Phone' reveals that a baseband beginning wth I9020 is the Super AMOLED or I9023 for Super LCD.

Comment: See also: [Difference between Super LCD screen of Nexus S and Super AMOLED screen of Samsung Galaxy S](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7135/difference-between-super-lcd-screen-of-nexus-s-and-super-amoled-screen-of-samsung).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which display did you end up having? I'm worried after seeing the things on the internet comparing them both, so I really don't know whether to risk it or not. If you do have one with SLCD, is it as bad as you maybe thought?

Comment: Got AMOLED, happy with it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at something black (e.g. an image of only black) on your phone, and shut off the lights.  If you've got an AMOLED screen, it should be pure black (virtually no light emanating).  With an LCD it will be significantly brighter/greyish.

Comment: I will try tonight!

Comment: This proved to be correct and confirmed with baseband version.

Answer (score -1):

regarding if the Super AMOLED is inferior:
Android update 2.3.3 introduced a color temperature correction, which many users complain turned their screen color "ugly and yellowish" http://www.androidcentral.com/nexus-s-233-update-bringing-unwanted-screen-issues.

The color change appears to still be present in the newer 2.3.4 update, and some have begun to suspect that the fact that not everyone is seeing this color change, may be related to which screen the phone has; with the SuperAMOLED being associated with the yellowish color and the LCD not having the yellowish color.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Al Theoretically, if you have the update you could tell what screen you have by having or not having the yellow colour ...