# Nexus S screen question

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Super LCD screen of Nexus S and Super AMOLED screen of Samsung Galaxy S](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7135/difference-between-super-lcd-screen-of-nexus-s-and-super-amoled-screen-of-samsung)

On the US site of Nexus S they say it have Super AMOLED screen. In my country, Serbia, cell network is selling this phone but states that Nexus S have Super LCD screen. Do diferent Nexus S devices have different screens? Is Super LCD to bad comparing to Super AMOLED?

Comment: Related: [How do I detect if I have a Super AMOLED or LCD Screen on my Nexus S?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-do-i-detect-if-i-have-a-super-amoled-or-lcd-screen-on-my-nexus-s) Also related: [Difference between Super LCD screen of Nexus S and Super AMOLED screen of Samsung Galaxy S](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7135/difference-between-super-lcd-screen-of-nexus-s-and-super-amoled-screen-of-samsung)

Comment: I think this is sufficiently similar to the second question linked to be eldarerathis to close as a duplicate.  Yes, the Nexus S has been produced with different versions/screens; the other questions have any other details you should need :)